# Basic Naive Set Theory Question on Segments of Sets in addition to Ordinality

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I am working in Keith Devlin's Second Edition: Joy of Sets. Page. 18, after Theorem 1.7.3. He writes as follows: " Let $(X,\leq)$ be a woset (i.e. well-ordered set), $a \in X$. By segment $X_a$ of $X$ determined by $a$ we mean the set:

$X_a = \{ x \in X \mid x < a \}$

Very unclear as to what this means exactly. It is not the same thing as taking a segment of a line? 
The idea becomes important very quickly with Ordinality.

Devlin writes: "An ordinal is defined to be a woset $(X,\leq)$ such that  $X_a = a$ for all $a$ in $X$." 
Again: the meaning is not clear to me.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Re the definition of $X_a,$ how is it unclear? It is all of the elements of $X$ that are less than $a.$

Comment: As to the second question there's perhaps some confusion to be had as we're identifying a subset of $X$ with an element of $X$ which is not something that's seen a lot outside set theory. However, general in set theory, "everything" is a set... in particular any element of a set is a set. Here in the definition any element of must be the subset of all elements of $X$ that are less than it. (Consider the Von-Neumann representation of the integers for something that obeys this... these are just the finite ordinals.) However, you have said you are confused without saying why so it's hard to help.

Comment: For those of us who don't happen to have a copy of that book handy, do you mind telling us what a "woes" is?

Comment: woset-- well-ordered set

Comment: It is (somewhat) analogous to  a segment of a line. E.g. when $X=\mathbb N$ and $<$ is the usual order on $\mathbb N$ and $n\in \mathbb N$ then $X_n=\{m\in \mathbb N:m<n\} .$...   A different example: Let $X=\{0,1\}\times \mathbb N. $ Let $<_N$ be the usual order on $\mathbb N. $ Define $<_X $ by $(0,m)<_X(1,n)$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb N$ and by $[...(j,m)<_X (j,n)\iff m<_N n...$] when  $j\in\{0,1\}$ and $m,n\in \mathbb N.$  Then for $a=(1,1)$ we have $X_a=\{0\}\times \mathbb N.$

Comment: I agree that his def'n of an ordinal may seem opaque if you're beginning. A set $S$ is called transitive iff $\forall x\in S\;(x\subset S)$, i.e. all members (if any) of $S$ are also subsets of $S$..... An ordinal can be defined as a transitive set $S$ such that $\in$ is a well-order on $S.$